# Negative Testing on Paypal Sandbox on Nuget Package

Tags: c#, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to figure out how to do negative testing on the  PayPal sandbox using the Nuget package from https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK

I am using the call payment.Create(apiContext) and would like to test all the conditions for the errors.

I referred to the documents in https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-test-failed-transactions-in-the-paypal-sandbox-ts1259 but explains how to add request headers to the REST calls. I do not find such methods on the c# SDK.

any pointers will be helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no an official way to test negative conditions via .NET or java SDK.
Official documentation offers negative conditions only for REST and SOAP calls [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb-error-conditions/).

By the way I have been able to rise an error condition in this way:

1. Be sure your sandbox payer account has money enough to pay your item and keep a browser page open on 'edit payer account' page in your paypal development dashboard
   [image: pic] [image: pic]
2. Prepare the payment for the user and test it till the moment the sandbox payer arrive to the last step before paying
   [image: pic]
3. On the 'edit payer account' page (see pt. 1) edit the available amount of the payer to a **value lesser than the amount to pay (e.g. 1.0)**
4. Return to the payer page (see pt. 2) and press the 'continue' button. **Payment will fail with the code**:

   INSTRUMENT_DECLINED - The instrument presented was either declined by
   the processor or bank, or it can't be used for this payment.